# Setting up the Header Using Http to get the Json file

Tags: json, angularjs, http, binding, header

I do have a working table using JSON and angular, I set up my $http header to get the Json in the particular .api, I run it but nothings appear in getting my Json file in the $Http.get, I would like to ask if this is a valid header, I mean is there something wrong with my delimeter?

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
    myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get ("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {header: {Authorization: 'vsdnmsndjednmsdnjemsdjendmsdnjeNmJHMN'}}); .success(function(response) {
        debugger
        $scope.members=response.events;
         $scope.totals = response.paging;
    });

    });
```

Comment: Did you inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network? What does question have to do with the subject of `Filtering Table`?

Comment: Not sure if you have copy/paste and/or formatting issues... I'm assuming the **'s around the $http.get line were intended to highlight (bold) the line and are not actually in the code... likewise, you have blah; .success ... if that's actually how your code is written, that's a problem and might be a good chunk of your issue ... remove semicolon so it's $http.get(blah).success(function(response){//code});

Comment: @foon  the ** it is intended to bold  and it is not part of the code,,yes i run like what you have wrote like $http.get(blah).success(function(response){//code})     . but it is not working , my question is., is the allignment of the code are correct? or i mean did i miss a semicolon or such delimeter ,, because it doesnt work ,

Comment: @charlietft ow yeah tnx, i forgot to change the title of my question , sorry , , browser dev tools? yeah ,, actually i inspect and look if the events.json is compiled already , it shows in the network tab on my browser that my html file and events.json are in ,i mean are working through ,  but the output doesnt work , thats why i posted this , for someone who can suggest if there is  a missing delimter ,semicolon etc on my $http.get ,

Answer (score 0):

Remember about correct style guide. It should help you. Also check this link https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/

```
(function {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myTable', [])
        .controller('tableCtrl', tableCtrl);

    tableCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

    function tableCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {
            header: {
                Authorization: 'vsdnmsndjednmsdnjemsdjendmsdnjeNmJHMN'
            }
        }).then(function(response.data) {
            $scope.members = response.data.events;
            $scope.totals = response.data.paging;
        }).catch(function(error) {

        });

    });
}());
```

This query is wrong:

```
$http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {
            header: {
                Authorization: 'vsdnmsndjednmsdnjemsdjendmsdnjeNmJHMN'
            }
        }
```

You can pass parametes by get building query like this one:
`$http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/customer/1")` or
`$http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/customer/" + some_param)`. If you would like to send some object to you API you should use `POST`. For example:
`$http.post("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {object});`

Comment: i try ya code  , but nothings happens , maybe the problem is on my events.json , but if am going to run the events.json without header the table is working ,i did try your code by replacing my code starts from the var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]); and replace your code . starts with the  {function {